# How to Open MODAL after its been added to DOM - vue 3 bootstrap 5 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I dont know much about vue/bootstrap and reading docs does not help me to understand how it all works.

How to open a modal that is created after the page was loaded. From user input. User clicks button then the modal loads into a list prop and then renders into DOM and then it opens up.

Im at the point where i created event when user clicks the button that loads the modal into the list, but how do you catch the "modal has been added to DOM" event and then you can use getElementByID to instantiate the modal and then use .show() to show it?

I can see that the card that supposed to render on the page loads/renders, but the method get null. Im guessing that the method runs before the page/DOM has been re-rendered. So how do you run another method with parameter of sorts after the custom event that added the item to list has been triggered?

The code is too big and convoluted to post. But if need be i could try to trim it down, but its  a mess.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container-center">
    <AnimeList />
  </div>
</template>
```

AnimeList.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="containerlist">
    <AnimeCardModal
      v-for="anime in animeList"
      :anime="anime"
      @checkAnimeListForRelatedEvent="checkAnimeListForRelated"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import AnimeCardModal from "./AnimeCardModal.vue";
import axios from "axios";
</script>
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  name: "AnimeList",

  data() {
    return {
      animeList: [],
      limit: 30,
      page: 1,
      reachedEnd: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getAnimeLsit() {
      const res = await axios.get("/api", {
        params: { page: this.page, limit: this.limit },
      });

      this.animeList = res.data.data;
      this.page = res.data.next.page;
      this.limit = res.data.next.limit;

 
    },
    async getNextBatch() {

      let bottomOfWindow =
        document.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight ===
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
      if (bottomOfWindow && !this.reachedEnd) {
        const res = await axios.get("/api", {
          params: { page: this.page, limit: this.limit },
        });

        res.data.data.map((item) => {
          this.animeList.push(item);
        });
        if (!res.data.next) {
          this.reachedEnd = true;
        } else {
          this.page = res.data.next.page;
          this.limit = res.data.next.limit;
        }
      }
    },
    async checkAnimeListForRelated(animeID) {
     
      if (!this.animeList.filter((anime) => anime.id === animeID).length > 0) {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/anime", {
          params: { id: animeID },
        });
       
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          this.animeList.push(res.data.data[0]);
          console.log("added to list");

        }
      }
      // Add the anime to the list
    },
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.getNextBatch);
  },
  deactivated() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.getNextBatch);
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getAnimeLsit();
  },
  components: {
    AnimeCardModal,
  },
});
</script>
```

Here is the method that gets triggered by the user click event where it loads the Not in main list data and should render on page/DOM.

```
 async checkAnimeListForRelated(animeID) {
     
      if (!this.animeList.filter((anime) => anime.id === animeID).length > 0) {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/anime", {
          params: { id: animeID },
        });
       
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          this.animeList.push(res.data.data[0]); <--------------------------------------
          console.log("added to list");

        }
      }
      // Add the anime to the list
    },
```

The added item is a modal with element id. I want to instantiate this element as new Modal() and open it with .show().

But the i get error that the element does not exist = null and i cant get it, but i can see it on screen.

EDIT:1

Ok so like as per usual, once i post on SO i find an answer to my problem, but it turns into another problem.

SO to get the rendered element i used this:

```
 async checkAnimeListForRelated(animeID) {
     
      if (!this.animeList.filter((anime) => anime.id === animeID).length > 0) {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/anime", {
          params: { id: animeID },
        });
       
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          this.animeList.push(res.data.data[0]); 
          console.log("added to list");
          this.$parent.$nextTick(() => {  <----------------------
            const myModal = new Modal(
              document.getElementById("anime-card-modal-" + animeID)
            );
            myModal.show();
        }
      }else{
            const myModal = new Modal(
              document.getElementById("anime-card-modal-" + animeID)
            );
            myModal.show();
}
      // Add the anime to the list
    },
```

It works, but now the modals overlay each other, seems like its not working like when you add the attributes to the card element that opens modal:

```
:data-bs-target="'#anime-card-modal-' + anime.id"
data-bs-toggle="modal"
```

Is there a way to get the same effect from method as with these attributes?

I want to open a modal, by clicking an element with those attributes, then when i click another element with them attributes (different target id) it closes previously opened modal and opens the target modal.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a solution, works pretty good.

Instead of using myModal.show() i used  myModal.toggle("anime-card-modal-" + animeID) and the else statement is not needed in the event method:

```
async checkAnimeListForRelated(animeID) {
     
      if (!this.animeList.filter((anime) => anime.id === animeID).length > 0) {
        const res = await axios.get("/api/anime", {
          params: { id: animeID },
        });
       
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          this.animeList.push(res.data.data[0]); 
          console.log("added to list");
          this.$parent.$nextTick(() => {  
            const myModal = new Modal(
              document.getElementById("anime-card-modal-" + animeID)
            );
             myModal.toggle("anime-card-modal-" + animeID) <---------------
        }
      }
      // Add the anime to the list
    },
```